# Why send data using ajax by input `type="password"` not work?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, passwords

Why send data using ajax by input `type="password"` not work ?

Main idea When i fill password less 6 char it's will display `Password minimum 6 characters`

OK, when i test on this code it not work, and then i edit code `index.php` from

`<input type="password" name="password" id="password"`

to

`<input type="text" name="password" id="password"`

it's work ok.

my question is , how to apply this code for using on `<input type="password" name="password" id="password"`

index.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
       var HttPRequest = false;

       function doCallAjaxpassword() {
          HttPRequest = false;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
             HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
             if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
                HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
             }
          } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
             try {
                HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
             } catch (e) {
                try {
                   HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
             }
          } 

          if (!HttPRequest) {
             alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
             return false;
          }

          var url = 'check_password_lenght.php';
          var pmeters = "CPassword=" + encodeURIComponent( document.getElementById("password").value);

            HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);

            HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", pmeters.length);
            HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            HttPRequest.send(pmeters);


            HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {

                if(HttPRequest.readyState == 3)  // Loading Request
                {
                    document.getElementById("mySpanpassword").innerHTML = "..";
                }

                if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
                {
                    if(HttPRequest.responseText == 'Y')
                    {
                        window.location = 'AjaxPHPRegister3.php';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("mySpanpassword").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;
                    }
                }

            }

       }
    </script>








        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" onchange="JavaScript:doCallAjaxpassword();" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']); ?>"> <span id="mySpanpassword"></span>
```

check_password_lenght.php

```
<?php
$strPassword = $_POST[CPassword];
            // ฟังก์ชันตรวจสอบว่า password มีความยาวเกิน 6 ตัวหรือไม่
            $strlen_password =  strlen($strPassword);
            if ( $strlen_password < 6 ) 
                {
                    echo "Password minimum 6 characters";
                } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better not to use XMLHttpRequest object when you have jQuery loaded on the page, its a waste of time.

HTML

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check_password_lenght.php",
    data: { password : $('#password').val() }
}).done(function( response ) {
    alert( response );
});
```

Edit it as you like.

Comment: Or save more time: $.post('check_password_lenght.php', $(this).serialize(), function(){ ... });